# What is the result of a number greater than 2 raised to the power of {Aleph-0}?

Tags: cardinals, infinity

So, I know that $2^{\aleph_0} = \beth_1$, right? What about another number, say $10$, raised to the power of $\aleph_0$? Is $10^{\aleph_0} = \beth_1$ also true, or is $10^{\aleph_0} > \beth_1$ somehow?

Comment: They are the same number. The number $10^{\aleph_0}$ is the cardinality of all sequences in $\{0,1,...,9\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any cardinal $\kappa \leq \aleph_{0}$, namely the finite ones and $\aleph_{0}$ itself, gives $\kappa^{\aleph_{0}} = 2^{\aleph_{0}}$. <strike>Any cardinal larger than $\aleph_{0}$ remains constant when exponentiated</strike>

Comment: Your second sentence is false: for example, by Konig's Theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nig%27s_theorem_(set_theory), $(\aleph_\omega)^{\aleph_0}>\aleph_\omega$.

Comment: I suppose you meant $\;\alpha >\aleph_0\implies \alpha^{\aleph_0}=\alpha\;$ ?

Comment: @Noah thank you for the correction. As I was formatting I started to doubt myself but I figured $\kappa^{\aleph_0} = \lim \kappa^n = \lim \kappa$ where the limit is over $n < \aleph_0$. Actually I still don't see the problem with this, since exponentiation is normal.

Comment: It is not true that $k^{\aleph_0}=k$ for every infinite cardinal $k.$ By Konig's Lemma ,$ cf(k^{cf(k)})>cf(k)$, which implies $ k^{cf(k)}>k.$  For example with $k=\omega_{\omega}$ we have $ k^{\omega}>k.$

Comment: @basket: _Ordinal_ exponentiation is normal in the exponent, but cardinal exponentiation is a totally different operation.

Comment: @basket. The cardinal $a^b$ is the cardinal of the set of all functions from $b$ into $ a$. The ordinal $a^b$ is the order-type of the set  $S$ of functions $f$  from $b$ into $a$ such that $\{x\in b: f(x)\ne 0\}$ is finite, where $S$ is ordered reverse-lexicographically.

Comment: It's been years since I've done any set thoery, so thank you all for convincing me to pick up Jech again...

Answer (score 4):

We have $2^{\aleph_0} \leq 3^{\aleph_0} \leq 4^{\aleph_0} \leq \dots \leq \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$, because of the inclusions $\{0, 1\}^\Bbb N \subset \{0,1,2\}^\Bbb N \subset \dots \subset \Bbb N^\Bbb N$. So if we prove that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$, then we see that all of these cardinalities are in fact equal.

To show this, we need to find some injection $f: \Bbb N^{\Bbb N} \to \{0, 1\}^\Bbb N$. There are many ways to do this; my favorite is as follows. Let $a = (a_n)$ be some sequence of natural numbers. Then we define $f(a)$ to be the sequence consisting of first $a_0$ ones, followed by a zero, then $a_1$ ones, followed by a zero, then $a_2$ ones, followed by a zero, and so on. This gives a sequence of zeroes and ones, and if $b = (b_n)$ is another sequence of natural numbers, then $f(a) = f(b)$ if and only if $a_n =b_n$ for all indices $n$ if and only if $a = b$. So $f$ is indeed injective, and therefore $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

So indeed $2^{\aleph_0} = 3^{\aleph_0} = \dots = \aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: I wonder if in $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}$ the top $\aleph_0$ can be the same as the bottom one : isn't it only a notation for $|\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}|$ which is only a notation for the set of (possibly infinite length) integers sequences, so that we get by definition $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0}= \lim_{k \to \infty} k^{\aleph_0} \le 2^{\aleph_0}$ because of the injection $\{0,1\}^{\lfloor \log_2(k)\rfloor +1}  \to \{0,\ldots k-1\}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Perhaps I'm misunderstanding your comment. You are right that $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = |\Bbb N^\Bbb N|$ by definition. However, $\lim_{k \to \infty} k^{\aleph_0}$ is equal to the cardinality of the union of all $\{0, \dots, k-1\}^\Bbb N$, and this union only contains the bounded sequences of natural numbers (for instance the sequence $(0, 1, 2, \dots)$ is not in this union). So while the equality $\aleph_0^{\aleph_0} = \lim_{k \to \infty} k^{\aleph_0}$ is true, it is not true by definition.